# create a json joining queries in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have two related tables, Areas and subareas. Each area has many subareas. I need to return a json where for each area all the subareas are shown in a json, in the way shown in the image.

[image]

I'm using laravel 5.4 and I do not know how to do it.

Area Model:

[image]

Subarea Model:

[image]

My Code:

[image]

sorry. I am a newbie in programming and new in laravel.

Comment: Show your model files and show your effort.

Comment: update my question I'm new to laravel

Comment: Are there any relations in the models? Then it would be easier to just get all areas and fetch the subareas directly within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have relationship set between the models, you can just do :

```
$areas  = Area::with('subareas')->get();
```

This will give you all areas and a collection inside each area with it's respective subarea.

You can go one step further and use [`API Resource`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) setup to structure the json response as you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2D array to convert it to JSON
Something like:

$areas = \Area::all();
$sub_areas = $areas->subAreas; // relationship

Iterate $areas using foreach loop and against each item, put it's subareas to some array
and finally json_encode that array

Comment: I tried to do it this way: 
        $areas=Area::all();
        
        $sub_areas = $areas->subareas; 
        $data2 = [];
        foreach ($areas as $key => $area) {
            $data2[] = [
                    'nombre' => $area,
                    'subareas' =>  $sub_areas 
                ];
           
      
        }
        return response($data2); but I get this error Property [subareas] does not exist on this collection instance. Im new in laravel. 
I appreciate the help